# create a page view to have only one specific content type show

Tags: views

I'm using D7 and I am working on a blog page. I have created a content type called News, I created a view called News as well.

I want to firstly create a page, all the content that the type is News will be shown on this page, but not other content type.

I can't find where to specify content type in the view settings. Both CONTEXTUAL FILTERS and FILTER CRITERIA seem only have all the content, but how do I specify content type?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under filter criteria, click on add, select **content: Type**, and then check the type you want filtered

[image]

Comment: By the way, when you create the view for the first time it has a content type filter preference :)